# Are there anonymous, type-safe, generic delegate signatures in C# 2.0?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Consider the delegate for a generic `A` to `B` function:

```
public delegate B Fun<A, B>(A x);
```

I can then write a function that accepts and invokes the `Fun` delegate:

```
public static B invokeFun<A, B>(A x, Fun<A, B> f)
{ return f(x); }
```

(Never mind whether it is wise to write `invokeFun`.)

Can I write `invokeFun` without *naming* the `Fun` delegate?  I would expect something like this to work, but it doesn't:

```
public static B invokeFun<A, B>(A x, B (A) f)
{ return f(x); }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there aren't.

The closest you can get is the two generic delegate families in .NET 3.5: `Func` and `Action`. Obviously they're not actually present in .NET 2.0 (except `Action<T>`), but they're trivial to write - and indeed I've [done so for you](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx) :)

Personally I'm glad the "uber-short" syntax is invalid - I find it harder to understand than the normal "here's the type, here's the name" syntax for the parameter.

Comment: I don't like the "short" syntax proposed, but I do find it annoying that there's no way to accept duck-typed delegates.  There are times when it's useful to specify that a routine wants a delegate that calls itself an `EventHandler<MyEventArgs>` rather than an arbitrary delegate for a method which takes an `Object` and a `MyEventArgs`.  On the other hand, in many case it would be helpful if every delegate of some particular signature were derived from the same common generic delegate type, and if those common types could be used as a generic constraints.